# Hiding a Html div with a selector and JavaScript not working so well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs with forms in them and I want to be able to have a selector and switch between the two.  Whitch I have, and it kind of works.  If you go to my JSFiddle and switch between the divs a few times you will see what I'm talking about.

here's my JSFiddle: https://urlzs.com/fN6YY

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.input_style {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.myform {
  width: 720px;
  background-color: #ffff4d;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: 40px;
  align: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", serif;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: 550;
  display: inline;
  margin: 15px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="container blue box" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <form class="myform" method="post">
            <h1 class="center">Square Root</h1>
            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Select:</p>
            <select class="input_style">
                <option value="blue">Square Root</option>
                <option value="red">Exponents</option>
            </select>

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Square Root:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the 
Number" name="number_1">

            <input class="input_style submit" type="submit" 
value="Calculate" name="square_root">

        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container red box" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <form class="myform" method="post">

            <h1 class="center">Exponents Calculator</h1>
            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Select:</p>
            <select class="input_style">
                <option value="red">Exponents</option>
                <option value="blue">Square Root</option>
            </select>

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Number:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the 
Number" name="number_2">

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Exponent:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the 
Exponent" name="exponent">

            <input class="input_style submit" type="submit" 
value="Calculate" name="exponent">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to switch between the different divs seamlessly.

Thanks A Lot!

Comment: Don't tell people to go off-site and play with the code "to see what happens": Clearly describe what you have, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, why you think that's happening and what you've tried to verify or even fix that, and how it failed. By all means, include a link to a demonstrator, but [all the information should be in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the dropdown value also when you switch.

```
$('select').val(optionValue);
```

updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lyn4dro/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
            $('select').val(optionValue);
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.input_style {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.myform {
  width: 720px;
  background-color: #ffff4d;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: 40px;
  align: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", serif;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: 550;
  display: inline;
  margin: 15px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="container blue box" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <form class="myform" method="post">
            <h1 class="center">Square Root</h1>
            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Select:</p>
            <select class="input_style">
                <option value="blue">Square Root</option>
                <option value="red">Exponents</option>
            </select>

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Square Root:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Number" name="number_1">

            <input class="input_style submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" name="square_root">

        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container red box" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <form class="myform" method="post">

            <h1 class="center">Exponents Calculator</h1>
            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Select:</p>
            <select class="input_style">
            <option value="blue">Square Root</option>
                <option value="red">Exponents</option>
                
            </select>

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Number:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Number" name="number_2">

            <p style="display: inline;" class="text">Exponent:</p>
            <input class="input_style" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Exponent" name="exponent">

            <input class="input_style submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" name="exponent">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works Great!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TylerPetrov. accept the answer if you got the solution

Comment: When I submit the form I just flash the answer on the screen.  Having that said is it possible to stay on the same form that got submitted after the submit?

Comment: change the type of calculate button to `<input type=""button">` and remove method="post" from form element.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't submit the form.  I'm using Flask if that helps.

Comment: @TylerPetrov The button type, that set it to 'reset' or 'submit' witch cause to page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS animations to obtain a seamless transition.

When the corresponding selector is selected , change the display property of the div.

Example:

```
    display:block  /*When div is needed*/
    display:none   /*When div is not needed*/
```

You could further use the CSS transition property to add the desired timings.

Another option would be to use custom CSS animations using the @keyframes property.
Using this will also enable you to have a animation timing function.

If you want to use Javascript as well , this article might help you : 
https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/